# Vim visual key input strange behaviour

Tags: vim

So i have following small test case

```
vnoremap <silent> d :<C-u>call Test()<cr>
vnoremap <silent> e :<C-u>call Test2()<cr>
fun! AskUser()
    let v = input('is this really ok with you? (y/n) ')
    redraw
    return v
endfun

fun! Test() range
    call AskUser()
    if 1
        echo 'hi hi hi'
        echo 'hi hi hi'
    endif
endfun

fun! Test2() range
    call AskUser()
    echo 'hi hi hi'
    echo 'hi hi hi'
endfun
```

So can anyone explain why visual mode d keybinding fails to show any message at all while
e keybinding works without problem

Note the problem is not related to keybinding at all but to a fact that
there is if statement after call to input function

I've tested it on MacVim and terminal vim on linux on latest vim versions compiled from mercurial source code and all have this problem

**UPDATE:** Some ppl didn't understood what the problem is. Well to be explained in details 
when you hit d in visual mode you get a input prompt and when you answer it you don't see any messages in command line while when you hit e and answer the prompt you see message hi hi hi twice in a row and 'Press ENTER or type command to continue' message

Comment: Both `echo` messages are printed with `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3` in Linux.

Comment: some ppl say you can if it works for you u can reproduce the problem by running vim -N -u none

Comment: Both print the `hi hi hi` for me with GVIM 7.3.000; please state the full version (inclusive patch number) instead of _latest_; patches are posted almost daily.

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep 26 2012 17:32:05)
Included patches: 1-672

Comment: And this MacVim VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jan  2 2012 17:38:47)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-390

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason of that different behaviour but testing I realised that if the function ends with the conditional `if` and last sentence is the `endif`, then messages are not showed in screen.

I've created a custom `vimrc` only with your code and I have run it with `vim -N -u new-custom-vimrc infile`. Like that, I can reproduce the behaviour of the question, but it seems to work when I avoid the `endif` as last sentence of the function, like:

```
fun! Test() range
    call AskUser()
    if 1
        echo 'hi hi hi'
        echo 'hi hi hi'
    endif
    let dummy = 1 
endfun
```

Also works this:

```
fun! Test() range
    call AskUser()
    if 0
        return
    endif
    echo 'hi hi hi'
    echo 'hi hi hi'
endfun
```