# vim script: can't echo newline after input and if statement

Tags: vim

The following function does not echo the result variable.

```
fu! Test()
  let input = input(">")
  let result = "error\n"
  if 1
    echo result
  endif
endf
```

Removing the newline from result, removing the input, or removing the if statement will fix this issue. Any ideas why this happens?

In my actual function the result variable is set from executing a system command and I would prefer not parsing/correcting the result before echoing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim visual key input strange behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621333/vim-visual-key-input-strange-behaviour)

Comment: Also see [this thread on vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/vim_dev/subject:echo/vim_dev/xNgJgBiKGIA). It is a vim bug, discussion of it must happen and happens on vim-dev, not on SO.

Comment: please add the expected out of the vimscript, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Vimscript can be strange. When I have issues with echo not showing when it should, usually a call to 'redraw' either before or after the echo fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `\n` newline with `\r`, [as mentioned at “How to replace a character for a newline in Vim?”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334/758011):

```
fu! Test()
  let input = input(">")
  let result = "error\r"
  if 1
    echo result
  endif
endf
```

Note that in running the above function I do not get the input cleared before `result` is echoed, so that if I enter `>foo` for the input, `result` is echoed directly and I get `>fooerror`. Echoing a newline before `result` is echoed takes care of this:

```
fu! Test()
  let input = input(">")
  let result = "error\r"
  if 1
    echo "\r"
    echo result
  endif
endf
```